# Can I use Android SDK to test a handset?

Tags: android, testing, sdk

I have an android phone, which I want to control using the SDK to send calls, receive calls , start some application, tap the screen etc.
Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an android application that does most of those things.  For screen-tapping, there is [Monkey.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html)

> The Monkey is a program that runs on your emulator or device and generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks, touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-level events. You can use the Monkey to stress-test applications that you are developing, in a random yet repeatable manner.